# Why is it recommended to not use inline conditionals?

Tags: java, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

I've noticed that style checkers give you a warning when inline conditionals are implemented: "Do not use inline conditionals". Why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it's because of code readability.

Consider this two codes, where `a` is a number (`int`, `float`, or whatever):

**#1**

```
if(a < 0) {
    a = 0;
} else if(a < 10) {
    a = 10;
} else if(a < 20) {
    a = 20;
} else if(a < 30) {
    a = 30;
}
```

**#2**

```
a = a < 0 ? 0 : a < 10 ? 10 : a < 20 ? 20 : a < 30 ? 30 : a;
```

They do exactly the same thing, but the first one is more clear.

Answer (score 3):

It takes effort to understand what going around in a inline conditional. If there is only one condition, it is preferred to use the conditional operator. For more that one conditions, if-else-if construct is better due to the ease of readability.